# How to view source of "string.h" and other library function source code in gedit of Ubuntu?

Tags: libraries, source, function

I remember viewing source code of library function but now I don't know how to view it. How to view the source code of library function?

Answer (score 3):

Try /usr/include/. If you're not able to find it there, try:

```
find /usr/include/ -name string.h
```

Answer (score 2):

`*.h` files are header files and usually holds limited functionality. To view the source for functions you need to download the/a C-library. On Ubuntu you can do e.g.:

```
apt-get source libc6
```

Then enter the newly created directory and play around.

To make the browsing more pleasant use an indexing program like [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). Doubt gedit has any integrated support for it, but other tools such as (G)vim gives you the opportunity to connect to the [cscope database internally](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html).

As such, you can press a sequence of keys to jump to declaration of functions etc.

---

On the web [this](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/) can be of help if you are interested in `glibc`.

You might also find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7778034/1968548) helpful.

Comment: Do you know any way to view source of library function using codeblocks?

Comment: @Habi: Not tested it. But they have [this plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Cscope_plugin) for cscope.